# GAE Thread is legal but not run

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

The following code is legal in GAE. But seems to never run correctly(the log line).
   when I use

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(factory);
```

it will get **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Each request cannot exceed 50 active threads**.
So I limit it to 10.

```
ThreadFactory factory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10,factory);
executor.execute(ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(new Runnable() {
@Override
       public void run() {
           log.severe(" can run here.... " );
           Movie m = insertMovie(pm, id);//But cannot enter this method!!
       }
}));
```

Fine.Who can tell me why. And how to run multiThreading in GAE.

Comment: Are you running this in an autoscaled module (the default) or in a manual scaling or basic scaling module? Autoscaled modules are meant to serve user requests, and threads can't outlive the 60-seconds-al-most deadline. If you want serious threading, it has to be on a manual or basic scaling module. As you don't mention module scaling at all, it seems you may not be aware of this crucial distinction.

Comment: I use it in doGet() servlet that execute a query from gae and do a web parsing by thread.

Comment: I do a web scraper by cron xml, but is take over 10 mins in GAE. So I want to use thread to do it . But I don't know how to use thread in GAE.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The OP clarified in a comment:

> I do a web scraper by cron xml, but is take over 10 mins in GAE. So I want to use thread to do it . But I don't know how to use thread in GAE

A thread, if it is run on an autoscaled module (such as the default module typically is), would not help -- it would be killed when the time-out occurs, and that time-out would *still* be 10 minutes.

Rather, the simple solution is to use an appropriate *module* -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ . The table "Scaling Types" clearly shows: background threads are *not* allowed in Automatic Scaling modules, but they *are* allowed in Manual Scaling and Basic Scaling ones. Therefore, use a Manual or Basic module for work that needs to run longer than the deadlines an Automatic module would allow.

For the requirements the OP expresses, a single-instance Basic module (with a small, thus cheaper, instance class, as scraping is not very CPU and memory intensive) might be just about right, i.e, in the web.xml and appengine-web.xml configuration files (as usually used in Java), perhaps something like

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>your-app-here</application>
  <module>scraper</module>
  <version>one</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <instance-class>B2</instance-class>
  <basic-scaling>
    <max-instances>1</max-instances>
    <idle-timeout>10m</idle-timeout>
  </basic-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

in addition to whatever other modules may be needed (typically, for example, an automatically scaled `default` module to serve user traffic).

There are other steps needed to convert your GAE app (which by default uses a single automatically scaled module named `default`) to use multiple modules -- the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ are very detailed, and in addition you can get specific instructions on how to migrate an existing GAE app to use modules, at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting .

Once you've migrated, you might then use threads in your basic scaling module, though that may not be needed, since the key objective (removing the 10-minutes deadline to completion) is obtained, threads or not, just by the code running on a basic scaling module.

An alternative architecture would be to use a [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) -- in that case, the task handler (if running on an automatic scaled module) would *still* have a 10-minutes deadline; however, shortly before deadline, App Engine raises a DeadlineExceededException that your code can catch to save any work already done and queue another task to continue from where the first one left off. However, while a very solid architecture, this might require more rework on your scraping task, than simply doing away with the deadline, by using a basic scaling module as I've recommended above.